# Multiple select option with checkboxes select and deselect option using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple option with checkboxes. I am working like this **All Batches** option is only selected bydefault and other options are deselect

- When I select **Batch01** option or other option then **All Batches** option is deselect
- When I select **All Batches** option then **Batch01** or other option is deselect

**Issue**

- When I select **All Batches** option then **Batch01** or other option should not be deleselcted.

Jquery script called for click events.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#batchid").change(function() {
    var batchid = $(this).val();
    var str_bat = batchid.toString();
    if (str_bat.search("All") != -1) {
      if (str_bat.search(",") != -1) {
        $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', false);
        var res1 = str_bat.split(",");
        if (res1[1] != '' && (res1[0] != 'All' || res1[0] == 'All')) {
          $('#batchid option[value=' + res1[1] + ']').prop('selected', true);
          $('select').material_select();
          $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', false);
          $('select').material_select();
        } else if (res1[0] == 'All' && (res1[1] != '' || res1[1] == '')) {
          $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', true);
          $('select').material_select();
          $('#batchid option[value=' + res[1] + ']').prop('selected', false);
          $('select').material_select();
        } else {}
      } else {
        alert("ALL Check");
        $("#batchid option").each(function(i) {
          $('#batchid option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('selected', false);
          $('select').material_select();
        });
        $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', true);
        $('select').material_select();
      }
    }
    if (str_bat.search(",") != -1) {
      $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', false);
      var res = str_bat.split(",");
      //alert(res[0]+' '+res[1]);
      if (res[1] != '' && res[0] != 'All') {
        $('#batchid option[value=' + res[1] + ']').prop('selected', true);
        $('select').material_select();
        $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', false);
        $('select').material_select();
      }
      if (res[0] == 'All' && res[1] == '') {
        $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', true);
        $('select').material_select();
        $('#batchid option[value=' + res[1] + ']').prop('selected', false);
        $('select').material_select();
      }
    }
  });
});


asp.net aspx engine code
```

```html
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s3"><label for="batchid">Batch</label>
  <select id="batchid" data-rel="chosen" name="batchid[]" class="form-control" multiple>
    <option value="All" selected>All Batches</option>
    <option value="1" selected>Batch01</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Batch02</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) and [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

`find("option:selected")` will find all the selected options inside `select` and`removeAttr("selected")` will deselect all the selected.

```js
$("#batchid").change(function(){

  if ($(this).val() == "All")
  {
    $(this).find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    $(this).find('option[value="All"]').prop("selected", true);
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).find('option[value="All"]').removeAttr("selected");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s3"><label for="batchid">Batch</label>
  <select id="batchid" data-rel="chosen" name="batchid[]" class="form-control" multiple>
    <option value="All" selected>All Batches</option>
    <option value="1" selected>Batch01</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Batch02</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using Materialized theme... so  its not working on that theme

Comment: What version? Could you add those js and css links in your question?